# Replace pattern Ignoring character in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a phone number as `phone= 1234567890`. I can use regex to format it as

```
phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3")
```

Given the string (123) 426-7890, how can a match a substring ignoring the space, hyphen and backet characters? For example, I want to search of the string 342 or 67. How do I write a regex to find these substrings, ignoring the characters `)` and `-` occurring between characters in these substrings?

Comment: normalize your data before you apply the regex

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) - [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Comment: If you already have `phone=1234567890` then why are you searching in formatted string?

Comment: i  want to highlight the substring so will wrap the substring into a span. The goal is to find. ex (12<span>3) 42</span>6-7890

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the non-digits with `\D+` regex (1 or more non-digit symbols) before the search:

```js
var s = "(123) 426-7890";
if (s.replace(/\D+/g, "").indexOf("342") > -1) {
  alert("Found 342");
}
```